# How to do the modulo operation in ARM assembly?

Tags: arm

I'm trying to add the values in two registers, and modulo them by 8.
So, in C code, it would be like this

```
a = a + b;
c = a % 8;
```

how to do this above operation in ARM assembly.

Answer (score 4):

Not all ARM processors have a direct instruction for division or modulo, so in most cases, a call to the modulo operation would end up as a function call to e.g. `___modsi3`.

In this particular case, when doing modulo for 8, if the values can be assumed to be nonnegative, you can do the `% 8` part as `& 7`. In that case, the assembly for your case would be:

```
add rA, rA, rB
and rC, rA, #7
```

Comment: What case is this assuming since it fails for certain values; e.g., 71 mod 15 = 6 test=11. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: modulo 8 is an and with 7, because 8 is a power of 2.  but modulo 15 is a completely different thing you cant use base 2 and operations you have to actually divide.

Comment: @old_timer, yeah I assumed that may have been the case. I have used a subtraction based mod function; however, it's much slower than a div (where available) based mod function due to the loops.