# What to and a random number with to constrain range between 0 to 9 in ARMv8 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, random, arm, armv8

I am trying to create an array of random numbers in ARMv8.

I am successful in creating an array of random numbers, however, my instruction which constrains the array; specifically the `and` instruction and the cmp are constraining it to a range of 0 to 12 instead of 0 to 9.

here's my code:

```
bl   rand               //branch to random num
and  x22, x0, 0x0C      
add x18,x18, x22        
cmp x22,x23             //compare x23 register to x22
b.lt mini               //branch to minimum calculation
```

as you can see I'm using and x0 with 0x0C which is 12 in hex.

Some say the best would be do and with 0xFF or 255 in hex but this is giving me very large numbers and thus Ox0C is giving me the best results so far but not ideal as I need them to be between 0 and 9.

an example table I'm currently getting when running the program :

```
0 0 0 8 0
12 8 12 4 12
4 4 0 4 12
4 12 12 12 4
12 8 8 8 4
```

and the ideal table example (I just removed 1 or 2 from 12 to demonstrate single digit random table, this is not an actual generation):

```
0 0 0 8 0
2 8 1 4 2
4 4 0 4 1
4 1 1 2 4
1 8 8 8 4
```

Comment: `0xc` is 12 not 13. Also you can't use `and` for `0-9`. You can use division remainder instead.

Comment: @Jester was a typo, fixed. I tried using division remainder before but was told using bitwise and is better for results.

Comment: Bitwise `and` works with powers of two. If you are happy to have `0-7` or any 8 values from `0-9` (meaning you omit 2 numbers of your choice) you can use it.

Comment: ok so I figured it out. What I did was just change the cmp to `cmp x0, 9` and it constrains the range.

Comment: since we cant see the rest of the code, that is not a correct statement, cmp by itself wont constrain it you need to loop.    if rand produces a 32 bit number then 99.99999998% percent of the time it will fail the comparison.

Comment: if you leave the and in there then the possible values are 0, 4, 8, and 12, so 75% of the time it will pass the comparison, but your only "random" numbers will be 0, 4, and 8.

Comment: @old_timer hmm. I've run it through quite a few times now and I'm getting all numbers between 0 and 9 . Stil don't see the leak you're referring to but maybe I haven't run it enough times (about 20 times with a 5x5 table).

Comment: See [How to do the modulo operation in ARM assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938673/how-to-do-the-modulo-operation-in-arm-assembly)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks, this was my next question.

Comment: @mikejosnton, using the modulo operator to reduce the range of a random-number generator is risky unless you know the generator is high-quality.  For example, one popular RNG generates numbers that alternate between even and odd; if you use `mod 2` to get a number that's either 0 or 1, it becomes an alternating sequence of 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done using only `and`.  The bit patterns for 1, 2, 4, and 8 are

```
0b0001
0b0010
0b0100
0b1000
```

The only bitmask that permits all of them is 0b1111, which permits any number up to 15.  If you want to constrain your values to the range 0-9, you've got two basic options:

1. You can use integer division to reduce the range of a generator with a larger range.  This tends to produce a slight bias towards certain numbers.
2. You can `and` with a bitmask of `0x0f` to reduce the range to 0-15.  If the number is larger than 9, you discard it and generate a new random number.  This is unbiased, but has no guarante of how long it will take to generate an acceptable number.